# What chapter of Berserk's manga did the anime Berserk (2017) episode 12 end?

Tags: berserk

I have finished watching *Berserk (2017)* and would like to continue reading the manga.

On what chapter of *Berserk*'s manga did the anime end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anime ends on Chapter 249. You can start reading from chapter 250.

---

Manga chapter 249, page 21

[image]

Anime episode 12, the scene at 23:22

[image]

---

Some of users on Reddit said

> Aaaand it's a bad idea. I mean, a really BAD idea. You can't start
> reading from where the anime ended, you will be lost. Important plot
> points (I'm not talking filler here, I'm talking real important plot
> points) were skipped by ANY Berserk anime adaptation. I started
> reading from the end of the 1997 anime, you think I would be safe: I
> wasn't, cause I lost all the explanations given in Black Swordsman Arc
> regarding Apostles and God Hand. Berserk 2016 skips the Demon Baby,
> Berserk 2017 skips the Moonlight boy. And if we are talking about
> "normal" content that's been skipped...you'll lose the Wyald fight,
> Lost Children Arc, and tons of other stuff. READ FROM THE BEGINNING, I
> can't stress this enough. - [*BerserkGallery*](https://www.reddit.com/user/BerserkGallery)

---

> That doesn't even matter when the anime won't even tell the same history
> as the manga .... and I'm not talking about adaptations, I'm talking
> about shit like skipping WHOLE major arcs, or just removing completely
> VITAL screens and even characters from history...[*Dracsxd*](https://www.reddit.com/user/Dracsxd)